# How prevalent is profound criticism of Israel among Israelis?

Tags: united-states, israel, public-opinion, zionism

[A June 2023 piece in *Jewish Currents*](https://jewishcurrents.org/recent-polls-of-us-jews-reflect-polarized-community) discusses a number of polls which measure the extent of **criticism of Israel's existence and/or its relation to Palestine within the Jewish population of the United States**. [A 2020 Pew Research poll found](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2021/05/11/u-s-jews-connections-with-and-attitudes-toward-israel/) a small but significant base of support for [the boycott, divestment and sanctions (BDS) movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boycott,_Divestment_and_Sanctions) , at 10% overall and 18% for the non-religious. A July 2021 poll by the Jewish Electorate Institute found that 25% agree "Israel is an apartheid state" and 22% agree "Israel is committing genocide against the Palestinians." There are even 9% who agree "Israel doesn't have the right to exist."

**What are some comparable data-points for Israel?** [A list of BDS supporters on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_supporters_of_the_BDS_movement) includes a dozen or so Israeli intellectuals and public figures, mostly based on statements made back in 2014. Certain Orthodox religious groups with a presence in Israel, such as [Neturei Karta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neturei_Karta) and to a lesser degree [Satmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satmar), are known for holding anti-Zionist views.

These facts leave me wondering if the overall opposition to Zionism or the occupation of Palestine is significantly greater or smaller in Israel, particularly across major demographic divides like religious versus non-religions and Jewish versus Arab.

Comment: I suppose the question of what Zionism *is* may be relevant. Disregarding the more fetid corners of the conspiratorial Internet, where certain people use it as merely a byword for Jews, Zionism can span a variety of political philosophies, from the groups that want to eliminate the entirety of Palestine (or even Palestinians) to those that want an Israeli and Palestinian state side by side. Not all of those ideas are necessarily incompatible with some of the opinions expressed in the question.

Comment: Sure... "Israel doesn't have the right to exist," is more on target then the rest, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: @BrianZ "Israel doesn't have the right to exist" is also quite fluid, it can mean: 1. "Secular Israel has no right to exist", 2. "Religious based Zionism has no right to exist", 3. "Jewish settlements on former Palestinian land have no right to exist", 4. "Without giving citizenship to area C West Bank Palestinians, Israel has no right to exist", etc. A better question for such a survey would be: "What do you want there to be in place of current modern Israel?" (my guess is that very few will say "modern Israel", the extreme secular will say "Holland" and the others will ask for the Messiah").

Comment: If anyone has a better term to encapsulate the range of critical opinions implied by the question I'm open to considering it.

Comment: Made some changes to the wording. I expect some will further split hairs on this but I think the general thrust of the question is clear enough and factually oriented.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Personally, I would define "Zionism" as the assumptions that (1) there exists a class of people called "Jews", (2) there exists a country called "Israel", and (3) it is desirable to maximize the number of Jews living in Israel.  Of course, there are divisions over the definition of #1 and #2, and the *reasons* for #3.

Comment: @dan04 - I mean, the first two points are not politics at all, just a recognition of facts. Someone who denies the existence of Jews or Israel is not anti-Zionist or even anti-Semitic, just anti-reality. Even Hamas believes that Jews and Israel exist—their 1988 Convenant even explicitly affirms the existence of the later ("Israel will exist and will continue to exist until Islam will obliterate it, just as it obliterated others before it").

Comment: @dan04 this a rather strange program, especially point 3. The number of Jews in Israel has indeed exceeded lately their number in the US. However, this is not the point - the point is that Jewish people, like any other people have a right for their state - this is the principle of *self-determination*, declared in the UN charter. Herzl and his early followers were explicit that the existence of the Jewish state was necessary not for removing all the Jews to it (which was an early Nazi program), but to make Jewish people equal an accepted as any other people - French, Germans, British, etc.

Comment: Since October 7th pretty much everyone in Israel came to the realization that a 2 state solution won't work - keep in mind that this is pretty much what there was between Gaza and Israel, Israel had no control over Gaza, but they decided to fully militarize it and make it into a terror base. Also, many of the people killed on October 7th were pro peace advocates who spent their life helping Palestinians and advocating for them - the fact that they were murdered and abused like everyone else made Israelis wake up to the brutality of the Palestinian leadership.

Comment: By the brutality of Palestinian leadership I mean that even the PA was a terror group but instead renamed themself and started giving money to terrorists instead of having their own terrorists carrying out terror attacks. There is literally no normal peaceful uncorrupt good faith democratically elected Palestinian leadership.

Comment: re: "Certain Orthodox religious groups with a presence in Israel, such as Neturei Karta and to a lesser degree Satmar, are known for holding anti-Zionist views."  That's offensive.  The connection to the land of Israel is one of the central tenants of Judaism.  The fact that some fringe groups try to dismiss its importance doesn't change the mainstream views of Judaism as a religion.  Please, rephrase the question in a way that does not challenge the views which are central to Judaism as a religion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Israel has pretty strong left wing and extreme left wing, as manifested by Israelis support for parties like [Hadash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadash), or organizations such as [B'Tzelem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%27Tselem), [Breaking the silence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_the_Silence_(organization)) and so on. The extreme left may particularly support one-state solution (popular among European and American left, but contrary to the [two-state solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_solution) supported internationally by most western and even Arab states.)

This also can be seen from reading mainstream Israeli media, such as [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/) (the Israeli equivalent of New York Times/Guardian/LeMonde, available in Hebrew and English.)

However, one should not confuse criticizing Israeli government and policies with criticizing "Israel" itself: even the leftiest Israelis do expect that in the end they will live in peace and security alongside Palestinians - none of them is planning to ["move back to Poland"](https://jewinthecity.com/2022/05/should-jews-just-go-back-to-poland/) or elsewhere, as some Israeli "critics" occasionally suggest. Particularly not those who were born in Israel, especially in second or third generation.

There are also many prominent Israelis, critical of the government, but nevertheless supportive of their country - like Natalie Portman.

**Demographics**
One thing to keep in mind is that [only 73% of Israelis are of Jewish origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Israel#Ethnic_and_religious_groups) - the rest are mostly Palestinian Arabs and other ethnic groups, such as Druze, Arameans, Armenians, etc. Palestinian Israelis are often critical of their country, as can be seen by their representation in the Parliament, which until recently consistently refused to join any government coalitions. Some of the Arab politician voice publicly the views as extreme as those of BDS like [Haneen Zoabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haneen_Zoabi).
[image]

**Political composition**
In addition to Palestinian parties, there are also mixed Arab-Israeli party [Hadash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadash). There are also Palestinian members of what is traditionally considered Jewish parties - like [Ghaida Rinawie Zoabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghaida_Rinawie_Zoabi), who is a member of Meretz, the party of Jewish intellectuals.

The rest of the political spectrum is split among more mainstream left, right, and religious parties (unlike in the US, religious and right-wing views are not necessarily linked - in the past religious parties also took part in left-wing governing coalitions.)

The full breakdown of vote for various parties can be found on [Wikipedia: 2022 Israeli legislative election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Israeli_legislative_election).

**Zionism**
It is necessary to note that political participation nearly excludes adopting BDS positions (with some exceptions in the Palestinian Parties and Hadash.) Indeed, [*Zionism is Jewish movement for national independence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zionism), and participating in the political system of the Jewish state means being a Zionist. In this sense opposition to Zionism is opposition to the existence of the Jewish state, a member of the United Nations, recognized by significant number of countries, including all of the western world.

In this sense, the use of terms *Zionism* and *anti-Zionist* by BDS, anti-Israeli groups, and some media coverage is misleading, perhaps deliberately so, and the OP seems to be influenced by this use. It is also worth stressing that Zionism from its inception was a *secular* movement for the creation of the Jewish state, as opposed to the religious imperative to move to the lands granted to Jewish people by the Almighty - in this sense *religious Zionism* is a misnomer.

*Zionism and religion*
[Naturei Karta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neturei_Karta) is a good example of how Zionism is in contradiction with the religious thought, since it implies that the laws of the state of Israel supersede the Laws of Moses. In a broader sense, there are significant [tensions between Israeli governments and the Jewish orthodox religious communities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Israeli_protests), regarding the military draft of yeshiva students, obligatory education program, interference by social services in child abuse, etc.

This also applies to the settlement activity: [evacuating West Bank settlements](https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/middle-east/palestinian-territories/1691994678-israeli-forces-evacuate-illegal-outpost-in-west-bank-sparking-settlers-anger) built without appropriate permissions is also not an uncommon practice (e.g., those outside of the areas designated for building by the Israeli government or on the land not owned by the settlers.)

**Remarks**
While *Zionism* is sometimes used in a very broad sense - to designate any activities associated with Israel and/or Jews, it is largely agreed that [anti-Zionism implies opposition to the existence of the Jewish state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Zionism):

> Anti-Zionism is opposition to Zionism. Although anti-Zionism is a heterogeneous phenomenon, all its proponents agree that the creation of the modern State of Israel, and the movement to create a sovereign Jewish state in the region of Palestine – the biblical Land of Israel – was flawed or unjust in some way.

Note that this means opposition to the Jewish [right for self-determination, as defined in the UN charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-determination)

> All peoples have the right of self-determination. By virtue of that right they freely determine their political status and freely pursue their economic, social and cultural development.

Interestingly, some forms of anti-Zionism, notably those favoring one-state solution, also deny self-determination to the Palestinian people (i.e., neither Jewish nor Palestinian state.)

**Appendix**
Here is a short selection of articles published by mainstream left-wing daily [Haaretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haaretz) since October 7. The content is behind the paywall, but the titles speak for themselves. One can also read the comments section.
October 8: [*Editorial | Netanyahu Bears Responsibility for This Israel-Gaza War*](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/editorial/2023-10-08/ty-article-opinion/netanyahu-bears-responsibility/0000018b-0b9d-d8fc-adff-6bfd1c880000)
October 19 [*Opinion | The War in Gaza Must Stop Immediately*](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/2023-10-19/ty-article-opinion/.premium/the-war-in-gaza-must-stop-immediately/0000018b-43ec-d614-abcf-ebff3ecd0000)
October 21: [*Opinion | The Secret to Netanyahu's Gaza Failure: Do Nothing*](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/2023-10-21/ty-article-opinion/.premium/the-secret-to-netanyahus-gaza-failure-do-nothing/0000018b-4e41-dbe0-a38b-cff5a0de0000)
October 23: [*Opinion | In Gaza, Israel Is Racing to the Moral Abyss*](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-10-23/ty-article-opinion/.premium/in-gaza-israel-is-racing-to-the-moral-abyss/0000018b-57d1-d8e2-a1eb-f7d7dc100000)
October 26: [*Opinion | It Is Forbidden to Even Empathize With Innocent Gazans*](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/2023-10-26/ty-article-opinion/.premium/and-darkness-was-upon-the-face-of-israel/0000018b-6813-d78a-a5eb-7c93d6fe0000)
December 9: [*The Israeli Army Has Dropped the Restraint in Gaza, and the Data Shows Unprecedented Killing*](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-12-09/ty-article-magazine/.highlight/the-israeli-army-has-dropped-the-restraint-in-gaza-and-data-shows-unprecedented-killing/0000018c-4cca-db23-ad9f-6cdae8ad0000)
December 10: [*Analysis | Netanyahu Must Be Politically Destroyed, or Israel Will Go Down With Him*](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-12-10/ty-article/.premium/netanyahu-must-be-politically-destroyed-or-israel-will-go-down-with-him/0000018c-530f-db23-ad9f-7bdfeca10000)

Here is from the right-wing [*The Times of Israel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times_of_Israel):
October 8: [*Op-ed | For years, Netanyahu propped up Hamas. Now it’s blown up in our faces*](https://www.timesofisrael.com/for-years-netanyahu-propped-up-hamas-now-its-blown-up-in-our-faces/)

I think these qualify as *"profound criticism of Israel"*. Their main distinction with the rhetoric of Israel's critics from abroad is that, while supporting Palestinians and criticizing Israel, Haaretz writers are not anti-Israel and not anti-Zionist.

**Update: Academic criticism**
Something that I forgot to mention inn my initial answer is the academic criticism, notably from the revisionist Israeli historians, who essentially support the Palestinian narrative - see [New historians.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Historians) In [the words of a Palestinian historian Rashid Khalidi](https://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Iron_Cage.html?id=x5znEAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y):

> In this sense, the “revisionist” works written by a number of Israeli historians and social scientists—Avi
> Shlaim, Ilan Pappé, Tom Segev, Benny Morris, and others 31 —are
> fully within this tradition, for what they are arguing against is the
> nationalist mythology of the state of Israel as it has informed and
> shaped Israeli accounts of that country’s history. That mythology is
> additionally the backbone of the received version of the history of
> the conflict as it is perceived in the West.

Describing Israeli history and current events with terms such as *ethnic cleansing*, *genocide*, *occupation*, *oppression*, *violation of human rights*, *colonization* is commonplace in Israeli academia, as evidenced by the [wholesale attacks on the Israeli academic institutions by the right-leaning organizations, such as *Im Tirzu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Im_Tirtzu#Alleging_politicization_in_academia).

I am not aware of such tough criticism of their own country being widespread elsewhere in the western world, beyond singular personalities like [Noam Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky) or groups that are labeled outright *extremists*.

Comment: Some helpful points here... Do any of those groups or individuals mentioned specifically advocate for a one-state solution and are there any numbers that would indicate the rough order of magnitude for support of that?

Comment: @BrianZ your question is not specifically about one-state solution. In any case, it is beyond mainstream political discourse either in Israel or anywhere in the West. Meretz, the party representing "intellectual left wing" did try to conduct their own negotiations, known as "Geneva initiative". I think your question about the exact percentages is somewhat misguided - how many americans are left-wing? - hard to say, unless you mean specifically registered democratic voters. You can check on wiki results of various Israeli elections - how many Israelis are left-wing.

Comment: The question is broad but, misguided or not, public opinion polls were the primary focus.

Comment: @BrianZ let's start with the demographics - nearly 20% of Israelis are of Palestinian origin - these are critical of Israel and have their own political parties and representation in the Knesset, although until recently they have refused to join government coalitions. The rest are Jews and minorities like Druze, who split into right and left, with mainstream right/left and more marginal parties. Hadash is special, because it is an Arab-Israeli party. That neither right nor left dominates is seen from the frequent government changes and frequent *weak governments*.

Comment: @BrianZ *misguided* is probably too strong a word, but I have impression that the question is grounded in a stereotype that Israel is somehow *right-wing* and different from western democracies.

Comment: Many good points. One remark though : The section "**Zionism**" seems to associate *BDS movement* with *opposition to the existence of the Jewish state*. However, at least in its origin, the BDS movement is not opposing the existence of Israel per se but Israel's occupation of Palestinian land outside the 1967 borders. It is e.g. advocating for a boycott not of all Israelian products, but specifically of those produced in the West bank colonies.

Comment: @Evargalo I will check what their precise position is now. However, the OP specifically mentions their opposition to Zionism per se, and their use of term "apartheid" (with the implication that Israel, West Bank and Gaza are bantustans, which really should be a single state.)

Comment: My (not extremely well-informed) interpretation would be that there are different currents in BDS and it could debated whether it is anti-Zionist as whole. I've been convinced this term is maybe a bit too vague to be useful unless a group self-identifies as such and I'm not sure that they do.

Comment: @BrianZ using vague and suggestive terms is a propaganda tool - remember "1984"? There are also other problems with BDS - singling out Israel, and using the indiscriminate methods (the Boycott, divestment and sanctions) that are likely to harm many innocent people, including those that they pretend to defend.

Comment: I don't want to get into a debate about BDS but was the argument fundamentally different for the South African case it claims to be modelled after?

Comment: @BrianZ my understanding is that in the South Africa the fight for the  civil rights was largely peaceful - they didn't torture children in front of their parents, and didn't promise to commit genocide of the whites. I think supporting Palestinians and supporting Hamas is not the same thing - in fact, these are rather opposite things.

Comment: [Horrific torture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklacing) was absolutely used by some anti-apartheid actors in South Africa. You seem to be equating BDS with Hamas but the two are clearly not identical.

Comment: @BrianZ I am not equating BDS with Hamas - if BDS condemned Hamas and distanced itself from the acts of violence, it would be indeed a formidable movement. But it seems that they do just the opposite: see their statement from October 8 https://www.ngo-monitor.org/reports/compilation-of-ngo-statements-on-october-7-massacre-and-aftermath/#BDS

Comment: @RogerV. I see your point, thanks. The section of that document on Israeli NGOs is interesting to me in light of the original question.

Comment: @BrianZ, regarding South African torture, According to your linked article "this was a particularly gruesome form of mob justice, **reserved for those thought to be government collaborators, informers and black policemen**." Not to minimize the horrificness of that, but the mind-numbing stories coming out of Israel of Hamas torture inflicted on children and pregnant women etc. etc.  is a different level of depravity.

Comment: This is a great answer. But it could have been even shorter: Ha'aretz exists, and is allowed to exist by the Israeli govt - and look at its headlines. That's enough to show 1) profound criticism exists, 2) Israel is a true democracy where opposing voices are permitted to flourish.

Comment: @Evargalo BDS supports the so-called "right of return", ie allowing all descendants of people who left Israel since '48 to return. That would mean an end of Israel as a Jewish state. The founder of BDS has [explicitely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boycott,_Divestment_and_Sanctions#Right_of_return) stated that they are against "A Jewish state in Palestine". It's not about specific policy, settlements or 1967 borders for them. It is about the existence of Israel as a Jewish nation (and extrapolating from that, the presence of 7 million Jews in the region).

Comment: @tim Its rather BDS' opponents who conflate the right of return with the end of Israel or even the expellation of Jewish population. "BDS deliberately refrains from advocating any particular political outcome, such as a one-state or two-state solution" and "Accepting modern-day Jewish-Israelis as equal citizens and full partners in building and developing a new shared society" are other quotes from your wiki link, cherry-picking the other way. (and I'll stop here the discussion because we are almost off-topic)

Comment: @YouDontSay I agree with 1) but not with 2). The existence of free speech and criticism and a necessary but not sufficient condition for a full democracy. There has been some autocratic regimes in history which have tolerated opposition newspapers to criticize them but were denying other liberties. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/10659129221080921

Comment: @Evargalo you can check Israel's freedom index - it is a free society, on par with most European countries. Of course, if you are looking for something negative to say about Israel, you will find something - but few people are interested in such a biased approach.

Comment: @RogerV. I was not making a statement either way about Israel's regime. I was just pointing that freedom of press is not "enough to show (...) a true democracy" (in any country).

Comment: @Evargalo sorry, I was not paying enough attention. Still, freedom index is a good place to look at - they evaluate countries by many criteria. This answer certainly was not intended to he comprehensive in this respect.

Comment: @Evargalo Expelling of Jews from the region is the *best case* logical result of what BDS is advocating for & the idea that if you just get rid of Israel as a Jewish nation you can have a shared society with Jews as equal citizens is ridiculous. It's not what we see in other states in the region, and it's definitely not what Hamas wants. And most BDS followers know that.

Answer (score 0):

> **Questions:**
>
> How prevalent is profound criticism of Israel among Israelis?

Israel's electorate has a wide diverse variety of political views to choose from and the resulting elections have reflected the electorate struggling to find consensus just like everybody else.  This is reflected by Israel having 4 different governments in the last 3 years. 5 If Netanyahu is forced to step down before Jan 1.  That isn't out of the question.

- **Benjamin Netanyahu** 2022-present
- **Yair Lapid** 2022-2022
- **Naftali Bennet** 2021-2022
- **Benjamin Netanyahu** 2009-2021

Comment: People vote on things besides for the Palestinians.

Comment: ... quite unexpectedly